# Prism2/MVVM Close View from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

How do I close a View from its ViewModel?

I've a WPF window which has defined multiple Regions and being used as a Shell to host views for my application. I would like to have a View able to remove itself from the Region, or close it from a tabbed container. How can I accomplish this behavior from ViewModel.

Comment: with valuable comments from members, i were able to code this successfully. sample class of implementation is published as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really depends on your app architecture, but here's how I do it with Prism.

First I want to say, it is *ok* to have your VM reference the View just as long as it is not a concrete implementation of the View, ie, references by interface.

I marry the View and ViewModel using dependency injection, very similar to how it's done in the StockTraderRI.  So I have an IView and an IViewModel.  IViewModel has a propery called "View" of type IView.

From the code layer (for me, usually the controller...see StockTraderRI) that works with your regions, add the mechanism to remove your view from the region.

For example:

```
myRegion.Remove(myIViewModel.View);
```

If regions are handled by a controller, you may want to put a simple event on the VM to notify when a VM wants to be "closed".  You can also experiment with the IEventAggregator if you wish to use a weak eventing model.  If the region is handled in the VM, simply add that code there.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got the logic. But I'm stuck where I resolve the controller interface from the Module. I get a stack overflow exception. LoginController controller = this.container.Resolve<ILoginController>(); throws an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like your unity container has some circular dependencies going on and/or is incorrectly configured.  I would follow all the constructors and make sure each injected parameter looks correct.   If you can try pasting the container setup code and maybe a few classes constructors.

Comment: Hi pls check the code I've pasted as Answer to this question. Thanks again.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. My View constructor had wrong parameters which was throwing Stack overflow exception. I fixed those and it works.

Answer (score 7):

Since your `ViewModel` doesn't (and shouldn't) have a reference to the `View`, you can't close it directly. However, what you can do is add an `Event` in your `ViewModel` to indicate that it wants to be closed.

Josh Smith has written [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090071) showing how to do this (about halfway through the article).

Comment: Hi thanks, I've been through that already. But Josh's article does not use CompositeWPF, so I am wondering how I could implement such an event handler coupled with Regions and Bootstrapper of Composite WPF.

Comment: You'd take that code and instead of window.Close() as your handler, you would use regionMananger.Regions["MyRegion"].Remove(window)

Comment: @Anderson, In reference to you previous comment, I didn't understand, where do I call the regionManager.Regions[] ... from? is it from the view's code behind?

Comment: @Shimmy: that really depends. It would be wherever you have a reference to the object that is in the region. If there is a view in the region, it might be from the codebehind, but if you have a reference to the view in the viewmodel (some people do this) it could be in the view model. If it is the ViewModel in the Region and you are simply datatemplating in the view, you could just do all of this from the viewModel and use .Remove(this). It just depends on your situation.

Answer (score 4):

This how my Login module looks like:

```
    public class LoginModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public LoginModule(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    #region IModule Members

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.container.RegisterType<ILoginController, LoginController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        this.container.RegisterType<ILoginView, LoginView>();
        this.container.RegisterType<ILoginViewModel, LoginViewModel>();

        ILoginController controller = this.container.Resolve<ILoginController>();
        controller.Run();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is the controller:

```
    public class LoginController : ILoginController
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
    private readonly ILoginViewModel model;

    public LoginController(IRegionManager regionManager, ILoginViewModel model)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.model = model;
        model.RequestClose += new EventHandler(model_RequestClose);
    }

    void model_RequestClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        regionManager.Regions["LoginRegion"].Remove(model.View);
    }

    #region ILoginController Members

    public void Run()
    {
        // Register views here
        regionManager.Regions["LoginRegion"].Add(model.view);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
    public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase, ILoginViewModel
{
    IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    RelayCommand _loginCommand;
    private readonly UserProfileRepository _userProfileRepository;
    public event EventHandler RequestClose;

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loginCommand == null)
            {
                _loginCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => this.Login(),
                    param => this.IsValid());
            }
            return _loginCommand;
        }
    }

    public LoginViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository, ILoginView view)
    {
        this._eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this._userProfileRepository = userProfileRepository;
        this.View = view;
    }

    #region ILoginViewModel Members

    public ILoginView View { get; private set; }

    #endregion
}
```